# Javascript function getting called multiple times

Tags: javascript, event-handling, html5-canvas

This is a game i am making. I am getting a very wiered error. When i click on first tile i am calling afunction level3. Which draws few vertical lines. After that even clearing the canvas my level2 is being executed.

Need Help !

You dont have to look entire code. Just the level2 and level 3 function.Check Demo link.When you click on first tile "Trader" level3 is called but remains for a short time and again level2 is executing without even calling.

**SOLVED**

Fixed Demo :http://stndlkr200.github.io/bugfixed.html

Bug Demo : http://stndlkr200.github.io/testbug.html

```
 <html>
 <head>

  <style>
        *{

        background-color: black;

    }

  canvas{display: block;}
 </style>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

 window.onload=function() {


 var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
 var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

 var w=window.innerWidth;
  canvas.width=w;
 var h=window.innerHeight;
  canvas.height=h;

 var ctr=0;

  var words=["We Need Swaraj","Play for Change","Aam Aadmi Party","5 saal Kejriwal","AAP for      
   Change","Vote for Good","Arvind Kejriwal","Kejriwal Fir Se","We Need Swaraj","Play for  
   Change","Aam Aadmi Party","5 saal Kejriwal","AAP for Change","Vote for Good","Arvind 
    Kejriwal","Kejriwal Fir Se","We Need Swaraj","Play for Change","Aam Aadmi Party","5 saal 
    Kejriwal","AAP for Change","Vote for Good","Arvind Kejriwal","Kejriwal Fir Se","We Need 
    Swaraj","Play for Change","Aam Aadmi Party","5 saal Kejriwal","AAP for Change","Vote for 
    Good","Arvind Kejriwal","Kejriwal Fir Se"];

 var j=0;


  function box(x,y){
   this.x=x;
   this.y=y;
   this.xVelo=10+Math.random()*20;
   this.yVelo=1;
   this.width=500;
   this.height=500;

   this.r=Math.round(Math.random()*255);
   this.g=Math.round(Math.random()*255);
   this.b=Math.round(Math.random()*255);
   this.rgba = "rgba("+this.r+","+this.g+","+this.b+",1)";
   this.message=words[i];
   i++;


   this.draw = function()
    {


      ctx.strokeStyle = this.rgba;
      ctx.strokeRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);

      ctx.font = 'bold 50px Calibri';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline='middle';
      ctx.fillStyle =this.rgba;  
      ctx.fillText(this.message, this.x+this.width/2, this.y+this.height/2); 


       ctr++;
       if(ctr>7000){
        clearInterval(timer1);

      ctx.font = 'bold 50px Calibri';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline='middle';
      ctx.fillStyle ="white";  
      ctx.fillText("Vote For Honest Leaders", 400, 400);
      ctx.fillText("Vote For Kejriwal", 600, 30);
      ctx.fillText("Vote For Delhi", 1000, 400); 
      ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(200,56,78,0.4)";
      ctx.strokeRect(550,200,100,60);
      ctx.font = 'bold 20px Calibri';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline='middle';
      ctx.fillStyle ="green";  
      ctx.fillText("Lets Play !", 600, 230);


     }
      this.update();

    }


    this.update = function()
    {
          if(this.x < 0) {
        this.x = 0;     
        this.xVelo *= -1;          
         }


      if(this.x > w - this.width)
      {
          this.x = w - this.width;    
          this.xVelo *= -5; 
      }


      if(this.y < 0) {
        this.y = 0;     
        this.yVelo *= -1; 
      }


      if(this.y < h - this.height) 
        this.yVelo += .25;


      if(this.y > h - this.height)
      {

          //this.xVelo *= .5
          this.yVelo *= .5

          this.y = h - this.height;     
          this.yVelo *= -2; 
      }


      this.x += this.xVelo/5;
      this.y += this.yVelo/3;
    }
  }


  var boxes = [];


  function draw()
  {

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter"


    for(i=0; i < boxes.length; i++)
      boxes[i].draw();

    update();
  }


  function update()
  {

    for(i=0; i < boxes.length; i++)
      boxes[i].update();
  }


   var timer1= setInterval(function(){
    boxes.push( new box(0,0))
    },1000);


   var timer= setInterval(draw,30);


    canvas.addEventListener("click",play_function);
    function play_function(e){
    button_x=e.pageX;
    button_y=e.pageY;
     if(button_x<650 && button_x>500 && button_y<260 && button_y >200)
      start_levels(); 

     }

    function start_levels(){
     clearInterval(timer);
      canvas.removeEventListener('click',play_function);
       level1();
       }

      var level1=function(){

      ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
      ctx.font = '13px Arial';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline='middle';
      ctx.fillStyle ="white";  
      ctx.fillText("MufflerMan wants you to sketch something.. Please do",500,10);




       var dots=[];


     var dotXval=["500","250","150","720","850"];
     var dotYval=["100","250","300","250","300"];


        function dot(xcod,ycod,radius,value){
         this.xcod=xcod;
         this.ycod=ycod;
         this.radius=radius;
         this.val=value;
        }

        function create_dots(x,y,radius,value){

          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI,true);
          ctx.fillStyle="white";
          ctx.fill();

          ctx.font = '10px Arial';
          ctx.textAlign = 'center';
          ctx.textBaseline='middle';
          ctx.fillStyle ="white";  
          ctx.fillText(value,x-10,y-10);

     }


       function  startLevel(){

         var dotRadius=10;
         var dotsCount=5;

        for (var i = 0; i <dotsCount; i++){

          dots.push(new dot(dotXval[i],dotYval[i],dotRadius,i+1));

         }

        for (var j=0; j<dots.length; j++) { 
          create_dots(dots[j].xcod, dots[j].ycod,5,dots[j].val);

         }


        }

         startLevel();

     var mouse={x:0,y:0};


       var drag4sketch=function(e){

         mouse.x=e.pageX-this.offsetLeft;
         mouse.y=e.pageY-this.offsetTop;


       }


        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',drag4sketch);



        ctx.lineWidth = 6;
        ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';

        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(mouse.x,mouse.y);

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',sketch,false);

        },false);


       canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){

       canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',sketch,false);

       },false);



      var sketch=function(){

      ctx.lineTo(mouse.x,mouse.y); 
      ctx.stroke();
      }

    var time=0;

    var clock=function(){
   ctx.clearRect(1000,20,1200,200);
   ctx.font = '20px Arial';
   ctx.fillStyle ="white";  
   ctx.fillText(time++ + ' sec',1120,30);

   if(time>2){
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);


   canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',sketch);
   canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup',level1);
   canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown',level1); 
   canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',level1);
   canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup',sketch);
   canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown',sketch); 
   canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',sketch);
   canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',drag4sketch);  

    level2();


   } 

   }

  setInterval(clock,1000);

  clearInterval(clock);

   }


   function level2(){

     var m={x:0,y:0};

     var rect_cordsX=["100","300","500","700","900","1100"];
     var rect_cordsY=["50","160","370","480"];
     var hints= 
 ["Trader","Businessman","Student","Teacher","Writer","Scientist","Politicion","MufflerMan","Auto  
    Driver","Police","Doctor","Industrialist","Soldier","Musician","Cobbler","Social 
   Worker","MufflerMan","Engineer","Advocate","Reporter","Editor","MufflerMan","Poet","Actor"];

      ctx.font = 'bold 13px Arial';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline='middle';
      ctx.fillStyle ="white";  
      ctx.fillText("MufflerMan wants you to find his companions..Your Luck! ",620,10);

      var hint_cards=[];

      var hint_card=function(x,y,hint){
      this.x=x;
      this.y=y;
      this.hint=hint;

       }


   for (var i = 0; i< rect_cordsX.length; i++) {

    for (var j=0;j<rect_cordsY.length;j++){
    hint_cards.push(new hint_card(rect_cordsX[i],rect_cordsY[j],hints[i*j]));          

    }
    } 


    for (var k=0;k<hint_cards.length;k++){

      ctx.strokeStyle="white";
      ctx.strokeRect(hint_cards[k].x,hint_cards[k].y,100,80);

      ctx.font = 'bold 15px Calibri';
      ctx.textAlign="center";
      ctx.textBaseline="middle";
      ctx.fillStyle="white";
      ctx.fillText(hints[k],parseInt(hint_cards[k].x)+50,parseInt(hint_cards[k].y)+40);  
    } 

     function click_hint_card(e){

        m.x=e.pageX-this.offsetLeft;
        m.y=e.pageY-this.offsetTop;



            if(m.x>100 && m.y>50 && m.x<200 && m.y<130){

            console.log("Trader");
             level3();

            }


        }

          canvas.addEventListener('click',click_hint_card);

        }



      function level3 (){

           ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);

           ctx.beginPath();
        for(var x=100;x<1200;x+=100){
          ctx.moveTo(x,100);
          ctx.lineTo(x,200);
          ctx.moveTo(x,300);
          ctx.lineTo(x,500);
       }
      ctx.strokeStyle="white";
      ctx.stroke();

     }


     }

     </script>
     </body>

     </head>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setInterval(clock, 1000);` calls a block of code:

```
var clock=function(){
  ctx.clearRect(1000,20,1200,200);
  ctx.font = '20px Arial';
  ctx.fillStyle ="white";  
  ctx.fillText(time++ + ' sec',1120,30);

  if(time>2){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);

    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',sketch);
    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup',level1);
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown',level1); 
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',level1);
    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup',sketch);
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown',sketch); 
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',sketch);
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',drag4sketch);  

    level2();
  } 
}
```

I suspect it is the last line of that `clock` function that is causing your problem. Remove it and it should go away.

Comment: Yeah your direction helped me to figure out my mistake. I have edited your answer. Just need to add clearInterval before calling level2. Thanks!

Comment: One more issue. If you click on Trader Tile even for single click i m getting multiple console.log('trader').

Comment: but if i use jquery $("#canvas").unbind("click").click(click_hint_card) i am getting one console output for one click but with addEventListener i am getting mutiple for single click event.

Comment: I am having a little trouble following the flow of the code above, but it looks like your bind of the click event is happening twice. Check it out and see if you can trace the open and close of the functions. Make sure the `canvas.addEventListener('click',click_hint_card);` is not being called twice (maybe place a `console.log` ahead of it see how often it prints out.